# Creating column to store multiplied values from two other columns

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I'm new to the SQL and I have a problem with setting default value for a column using this command.
The thing is I have to get product's brutto price.

```
ALTER TABLE produkt
ADD vat DECIMAL(5,2) DEFAULT 0.23;

ALTER TABLE produkt
ADD price_br INTEGER DEFAULT var*PRICE_NET;
```

"produkt" is my Table
PRICE_NET is netto price of a product.

After trying to add price_br column I'm getting **"column not allowed here"** error.
I assume It's quite an easy task, but i can't really figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want a *computed* column, not a default value.  That would be:

```
ALTER TABLE produkt ADD price_br INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (var*PRICE_NET);
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Gordon's answer.

Whenever you are using `GENERATED ALWAYS AS`, you have the option to specify whether the generated value should be stored physically on disk or computed dynamically when queried.

```
ALTER TABLE produkt ADD price_br INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (var*PRICE_NET) STORED;
```

Storing the value on disk will improve the query performance, especially if you are querying this column frequently, sorting, indexing etc.